# Is it appropriate to use [先生]{せんせい} when addressing a ski instructor?

Tags: honorifics, sports

Is it appropriate to use [先生]{せんせい}, either by itself or as an honorific after their name, when addressing a ski instructor?

I'm not sure whether it'd be appropriate because:

1. Using 先生 in this context may be disrespectful of other kinds of teachers, in that skiing instructor may be a less honorable profession than other kinds of teaching.
2. It may be too formal or cold or impersonal, and therefore not appropriate for a recreational activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fine for ski instructors and pretty much anyone else who teaches you something.

Using it as an honorific after the name is a little more formal than just using `先生` by itself. But it conveys your respect and appreciation for the fact that they are imparting their knowledge to you. I think it's possible someone might correct you and say that just `さん` is fine, but I can't imagine anyone being bothered in any sense of it being inappropriate.

1. It's not disrespectful to other teachers. Simply put, who you address as `先生` has no bearing on who else is addressed as `先生`.
2. It's not too cold or informal, and can be kind of a fun joke. Sometimes I'll ask someone at a store or a waiter at a restaurant for clarification on some Japanese, and then say something like `「有難う、先生」`. Gets a chuckle.

Comment: ありがとう has kanji?!

Comment: 有難う、Dave M G-先生!

Comment: @silvermaple: Yep. So does どういたしまして.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: 如何致しまして!

Answer (score 6):

You can use 先生　to anyone who teaches anything in Japan. In traditional sports or arts, Japanese use [師匠]{ししょう}.

Comment: Is 師匠 for a one-on-one type of deal? In my 弓道部 (Japanese Archery Club) our "teacher" was 先生...For context this was a University club, in Japan, and he really didn't show up all too often, we were mainly instructed by our 先輩.

Comment: @shin Does it sound weird to use 師匠 for a tuition teacher?

Answer (score 2):

I'd never call my ski instructor '--さん'. Nor have I ever called my calligraphy teacher '--さん' or '師匠'.